# how can i find the sum of best 8 from the data

Tags: excel, sum

i have data in different cells but i want to use a function which can calculate the sum of only best eight scores excluding zeros and empty cells, any one with away out,thanks

below is my data
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the LARGE function with an array constant to specify that you want the top eight values:

```
=SUM(LARGE(A2:L2,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}))
```

or

```
=SUM(LARGE(A2:L2,SEQUENCE(8))
```

in Excel365